# Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin' While installing Drivelist

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, package

I have an electron project in which drivelist is used as a dependency. When I run "npm install",
I get an error stating node-gyp\bin folder wasn't found. Whereas, I have node-gyp\bin in my node modules, and even in c:\programfiles\nodejs ...." as opposed to what this error states.
I guess drivelist couldn't build from source code after installation. But, what is the walk arround ? 
I am stuck because of this.

> drivelist@8.0.10 install C:\Users...\node_modules\drivelist
>   prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
>
> prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=10.17.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
>
> C:\Users...\node_modules\drivelist>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node 
>   "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin" rebuild )
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
>   npm WARN repoApp-explorer@3.1.0 No repository field.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! drivelist@8.0.10 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the drivelist@8.0.10 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-27T15_58_03_598Z-debug.log

I don't know the cause of this error, since to me everything seems alright on my device, 
I went through every link I could find till now on the internet seeking for solution but I haven't found any solution yet. 
Please can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can delete `node_modules`, then `npm install` angain because in my case it's work